# Quote vs prepare and exec

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to know which way to use on PDO, is it quote or prepare and execute, which one is more secure and safe?

Prepare and execute:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
FROM fruit
WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
```

Quote:

```
$param1 = $conn->quote($param1); 
$param2 = $conn->quote($param2);

$sth = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
FROM fruit
WHERE calories <  '.$param1.' AND colour = '.$param2.'';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just some manual notes.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
>   strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements
>   with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate
>   user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound
>   parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL
>   injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated
>   queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form
>   of the query.

Also

> Caution Security: the default character set
>
> The character set must be set either on the server level, or within
>   the database connection itself (depending on the driver) for it to
>   affect PDO::quote(). See the driver-specific documentation for more
>   information.

Comment: If I understand, I should combine between both of them

Comment: @AbuRayane - I think you misunderstood.... it's pretty clear from these quotes that you should use prepared statements with bind variables instead of quote.... `you are __strongly recommended__ to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters __instead of__ using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement`  is pretty clear

Comment: So I should forget about quote and use prepare, bind then execute to make my codes safer

Comment: Precisely, that's exactly what the docs recommend, and what most security-conscious developers recommend

Comment: @AbuRayane , create a rule for yourself "use prepared statements always"